# Python importing works from one folder but not another

Tags: python, python-import

I have a project directory that is set up in the following way:

```
>root
   > modules
       __init__.py
       module1.py
       > moduleClass
           __init__.py
           moduleClass1.py
           moduleClass2.py
   > scripts
       runTests.py
   > tests
       __init__.py
       test1.py
       test2.py
   run.sh
```

In `runTests.py` I have the following import statements:

```
import modules.module1
import modules.moduleClass.moduleClass2
import tests.test1
import tests.test2
```

The first two import statements work fine, but the second two give me the errors `ImportError: No module named test1` and `ImportError: No module named test2`. I can't see what is different between the tests and modules directories.

I'd be happy to provide more information as needed.

Comment: What's your working directory when running runTests.py?

Comment: and what are the contents of the \_\_init\_\_.py in that directory?

Comment: Trying to reproduce, i got an error on the first import

Comment: @JohannesKeinestam I run runTests.py from root.

Comment: @BartoszKP all the `__init__.py` files are empty, although I did try them with path adding statements.

Comment: @user2255137 I've also built the exact structure you presented, and running runTests.py from root also gives error on the first import. Please try to create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that python didn't like the folder name tests. Changing the name to unit_tests solved the problem.

Comment: Really? I have a directory 'tests' in my own project and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

When you run a script, Python adds the script's containing directory (here, `scripts/`) to `sys.path`.  If your modules don't appear in `sys.path` any other way, that means Python may not be able to find them at all.

The usual solution is to put your scripts somewhere in your module hierarchy and "run" them with `python -m path.to.module`.  But in this case, you could just use an existing test runner: Python comes with `python -m unittest discover`, or you might appreciate something fancier like [py.test](http://pytest.org/latest/) (`pip install --user pytest`).