# Importing modules properly for unit testing in Python using pyunit

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-import, python-unittest

## Question on unit testing

**Goal**: The goal is to use pyUnit in testCalc.py to unit test the simpleCalc object in calculator.py.
**Problem**: I cannot successfully import the simpleCalc object from calculator.py into testCalc.py when testCalc is run from a separate directory in the project.
**Background**: The unit test in testCalc.py runs perfectly fine when it's included in the same directory as calculator.py, but when I move it into a separate folder and try to import the simpleCalc object defined in calculator.py, I get an error.  I am trying to learn how to use the pyUnit unit testing framework in a simple project and I'm clearly missing something basic about how to import modules for unit testing in a hierarchical directory structure.  The basic calculator_test project described below is a simple project that I created to practice.  You can see all the posts I've gone through already at the end of this post.
**Ultimate Question**: How can I import the simpleCalc object into testCalc.py with the directory hierarchy described below?

Github: https://github.com/jaybird4522/calculator_test/tree/unit_test

Here's my directory structure:

```
calculator_test/
    calculatorAlgo/
        __init__.py
        calculator.py
    test_calculatorAlgo/
        __init__.py
        testCalc.py
        testlib/
            __init__.py
            testcase.py
```

Here's the calculator.py file, which describes the simpleCalc object I want to unit test:

```
# calculator.py

class simpleCalc(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.input1 = 0
        self.input2 = 0

    def set(self, in1, in2):
        self.input1 = in1
        self.input2 = in2

    def subtract(self, in1, in2):
        self.set(in1, in2)
        result = self.input1 - self.input2
        return result
```

Here's the testCalc.py file, which contains the unit tests:

```
# testCalc.py

import unittest
from calculatorAlgo.calculator import simpleCalc

class testCalc(unittest.TestCase):

    # set up the tests by instantiating a simpleCalc object as calc
    def setUp(self):
        self.calc = simpleCalc()

    def runTest(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.calc.subtract(7,3),4)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I have been running the unit test file with the simple command:

> testCalc.py

## What I've attempted so far

**First Attempt**
I tried simply importing the simpleCalc object based on where it's located in the directory structure:

```
# testCalc.py

import unittest
from .calculatorAlgo.calculator import simpleCalc

class testCalc(unittest....
```

And got this error:
*ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package*

**Second Attempt**
I tried importing it without relative references:

```
# testCalc.py

import unittest
import simpleCalc

class testCalc(unittest....
```

And got this error:
*ImportError: No module named simpleCalc*

**Third Attempt**
Based on this post, http://blog.aaronboman.com/programming/testing/2016/02/11/how-to-write-tests-in-python-project-structure/, I tried creating a separate base class called testcase.py which could do the relative imports.

```
# testcase.py

from unittest import TestCase
from ...calculator import simpleCalc

class BaseTestCase(TestCase):
    pass
```

And changed my imports in testCalc.py

```
# testCalc.py

import unittest
from testlib.testcase import BaseTestCase

class testCalc(unittest....
```

And got this error:
*ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package*

**Other Resources**
Here are some of the posts I've worked through to no avail:
[Import a module from a relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/import-a-module-from-a-relative-path)
[python packaging for relative imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348452/python-packaging-for-relative-imports)
[How to fix "Attempted relative import in non-package" even with __init__.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536764/how-to-fix-attempted-relative-import-in-non-package-even-with-init-py/27876800#27876800)
[Python importing works from one folder but not another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24048203/python-importing-works-from-one-folder-but-not-another)
[Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Ultimately, I feel that I'm just missing something basic, even after a lot of research.  This feels like a common setup, and I'm hoping someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong, and that it might help others avoid this problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the testCalc.py file, add the following.

```
import sys
import os

sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('../calculatorAlgo'))
from calculator import simpleCalc
```

Comment: I've added a forward slash that was missing.

Comment: Messing with the path seems hacky to me.